# Is there any way to write setOnClickListener for Button in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, buttonclick

I am writing setOnClickListener for Button in Fragment in Kotlin, but it is not working and says "NullPointerException" in Fragment where btnAdd used row.

```
class TODOFragment : Fragment() {
private var works = ArrayList<WorkData>()
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:
ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.work_list, container, false)
    view.work_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    works = Database.database().getWorksByStatus(3)
    val adapter = WorkAdapter(works)
    view.work_list.adapter = adapter

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
        val dialog = AddProductDialog(context!!)
        dialog.setOnClickListener { title, description ->
            Database.database().addWork(title, description)
            adapter.data.add(WorkData(title, description, Status.TODO))
        }
        dialog.show()
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(works.size + 1)
        work_list.layoutManager!!.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount)
    }
    return view
}
}
```

Here is my activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_circle_bgn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I can't understand What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Your button is part of the inflated view.

To get hold of it you need to use it within it's view, as bellow :

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:
ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.work_list, container, false)
    view.work_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    works = Database.database().getWorksByStatus(3)
    val adapter = WorkAdapter(works)
    view.work_list.adapter = adapter

    view.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
        val dialog = AddProductDialog(context!!)
        dialog.setOnClickListener { title, description ->
            Database.database().addWork(title, description)
            adapter.data.add(WorkData(title, description, Status.TODO))
        }
        dialog.show()
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(works.size + 1)
        work_list.layoutManager!!.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount)
    }
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the [kotlin android extensions plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html),  you will need to find the button using something like.

```
btnAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd) as Button
```

before calling the `setOnClickListener` method

The same applies to any other view item defined in XML.